# how to wire a polarized wire to a switch?

Tags: wiring

So I have a work bench and I'm building a box that will cover all my cables and outlets and generally make my work area look a million times better. My biggest issue is I have two sets of led lights that usually I plug/unplug to turn on/off to the mains power however this project will cover my plugs so I cant do that so easily (I can open this box but the goal isn't to open to operate lights).

The main plan was to wire these lights thru a light switch that we have mounted on the outside like a normal light switch but I'm unsure how to do this given I can only find switches that require a ground but I don't have a ground. how should I go about doing this in a safe manner?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring you're trying to install these switches to?

Comment: any details of the power supply for the LED strips would help to,  it's likely that a ground is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Use a remote-controlled wired switch. Quick & easy solution. The inexpensive versions are limited in how much power they can handle, but that is not an issue for LED lights. Something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-15-ft-16-2-Indoor-Switch-Extension-Cord-White-KAB-1P-KAB-18/300726073?MERCH=REC-_-rv_search_plp_rr-_-311784166;311784164;-_-300726073-_-N):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm guessing here,  you say "polarised" and that suggests DC, so I'm guessing these LEDs run of some low DC voltage on a SELV circuit, for that grounding is not required. just run the LED cable to the switch.